# Problem with appending element to list in while loop

Tags: python

This method is supposed to collect the user's numeric inputs in a list (entryList) until the user types in 'done'. However, the entry List turns up empty/`[]`.

```
   def entryReader():
    while True:
        entry = input('Enter a number: ')
        entryList = []

        if entry.lower() == "done":
            print(entryList)
            break
        try:
            number = float(entry)
            entryList.append(number)
            print(number)

        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a numeric value.")
```

The expected output:`[input1, input2]`

Actual output:`[]`

Comment: `entryList` is at the top of the loop and is set to empty every time. Put it outside at the top of the loop

Comment: Move your initialization of ```entryList = []``` out of the loop

Comment: Flagging it for being non-reproduceable

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the entryList declaration outside the main loop so the list doesn't become empty every time the loop runs

```
entryList = []
while True:
    entry = input('Enter a number: ')


    if entry.lower() == "done":
        print(entryList)
        break
    try:
        number = float(entry)
        entryList.append(number)
        print(number)

    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a numeric value.")
```

Answer (score 0):

In while loop, in each iteration your entrylist[] initialize. So it becomes empty. 
So if you declare entrylist[] before entering into while loop,then it will not become empty after each input. It will append the new number with the entrylist[].

```
entryList = []
while True:
        entry = input('Enter a number: ')
        #entryList = [] // Becomes empty

        if entry.lower() == "done":
            print(entryList)
            break
        try:
            number = float(entry)
            entryList.append(number)
            print(number)

        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a numeric value.")
```